# Result out of SQL to list

Tags: sql, r, teradata

I have a data set out of SQL in a csv format and this is the table/data structure.

```
Order ID     Items
O1            Beer
O1            Wine
O2            Beer
O2            Wine
O3            Beer
O4            Chips
```

I need to convert this in R into the following format

```
O1 Beer,Wine
O3 Beer,Chips
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried the following :

```
# MOCK DAtA
o1 <- c("beer","Wine")
o2 <- c("beer","Wine")
o3 <- c("beer","Chips")
o4 <-c("Curd","chips")
o5 <-c("beer")
o6<-c("Wine")
o7 <-c("fruits")
o8<- c("wine","Cheese")

order <- list(o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8)

library(Arules)

dt <- as (order,"transactions")
```

- OUTPUT:

  ```
  str(order)
  List of 8
   $ : chr [1:2] "beer" "Wine"
   $ : chr [1:2] "beer" "Wine"
   $ : chr [1:2] "beer" "Chips"
   $ : chr [1:2] "Curd" "chips"
   $ : chr "beer"
   $ : chr "Wine"
   $ : chr "fruits"
   $ : chr [1:2] "wine" "Cheese"

  str(dt)
   Formal class 'transactions' [package "arules"] with 4 slots
    ..@ transactionInfo:'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
    ..@ data           :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5
  ```

Note: I cannot change this in SQL because I have 800K rows.

Comment: Please show some effort. What did you try so far?

Comment: `I cannot change this in SQL because I have 800K rows` -- What makes you think R is better suited than SQL for this problem?

Comment: I am new to R and still exploring it , I was able to convert the list to transactions and my thought process was to check to see if I can convert a transaction level data to list .

Comment: Of course you should do this in SQL, probably it will be much more efficient. What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Version Teradata 13.10.07.12

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. The first table content you posted has order ID and Items. You can insert them into a work table, add a third column in the work table which would store the DENSE_RANK() of the records, keep order id in the group by partition by clause and order by Items. After loading this table. You can simply make use of this statement. `COALESCE(MAX((CASE rank_col WHEN 1 THEN items END)),'')  || ',' || COALESCE(MAX((CASE rank_col WHEN 2 THEN items END)),'')   || ',' ||` and so on. But this has a shortcoming, you have to know the maximum number of items that will be present across any order.

In case you have XML functions running fine in your data base you can use the below clause ( this will overcome the shortcoming of the previous approach, but you need to make sure that this command is running fine )

`XMLAGG((items)|| ',' ORDER BY rank_col)  (VARCHAR(50))  custom_concatenated_items` . Hope this helps.

Thanks 
Aritra